# Algorithm to compute certain matrices of integer partitions

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I seek an algorithm that will enumerate all non-negative integer `K`-by-`K` matrices such that the rows and columns sum to given values.

To be precise: Given `K`-vectors of non-negative integers `m`, `n` with `sum(m) = sum(n)`, I seek all matrices `X=(x_{ij})` such that `sum(x_{ij},i=1,...,K) = m_j` and `sum(x_{ij},j=1,...,K) = n_i`.

Thus each row is an integer partition of the corresponding element of `n` and each column an integer partition of the corresponding element of `m`.

Comment: So always `K` = `|m|` = `|n|` (the cardinality of `m` and `n`) ? Could you add an example of one such matrix?

Comment: No, |m| = [n] will not in general equal K.  An example for K = 2, m = [3,4] and n = [2,5] is [[1,1],[2,3]].

Comment: Suppose you have a bag containing  balls of K different colors.  There are n_1 red ones, n_2 blue ones, ..., n_K black ones.  In total there are |n| = n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_K balls.  In dim light, you are asked to classify the balls as to color, placing them in labelled bins.  When all the balls have been classified, you have m_1 balls in the bin labelled "red", ..., m_K in the bin labelled "black".  The question amounts to finding all ways you could classify the balls to get the given m, up to permutations.

Comment: Sorry @גלעדברקן, you are correct if by |y| you mean the length of the vector y.  You are incorrect if, as I first assumed, you meant the sum of the entries of y.

Comment: The trouble is that the number of solutions is huge (e.g. number of 15x15 matrices where all rows and columns add up to 2 is `414517594539154672566000` (see A000681 in the Online Encycopedia of Integer Sequences), so no brute force / naive approach is going to efficiently find the number of solutions. You need to understand the maths of the situation. I'd follow up some of the references in the OEIS.

Comment: @pbabcdefp, I agree the problem scales poorly, but it isn't bad for small K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from the comments that you are looking for a name of your problem in order to find an implementation or some literature. So, your problem name is: "Enumerating contingency tables with fixed margins" and is actually very complex (except for the case with 2 rows and 2 columns). It is known to be #P-complete, even when you have just 2 rows and n columns. So, usually, approximating algorithms are utilized to count the solutions (or mcmc algorithms to randomly generate them).
Curiously, both D.Knuth and F.Ruskey leave the problem as an exercise in their respective books.
[This paper](https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/EFS%20NSF%20452.pdf) provides a good (not up-to-date) review of exact and approximate algorithms. 
A typical application is in statistics for computing Fisher's Exact Test, so searching for this gives good results too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a hard problem. Given a partial assignment of the matrix entries, there exists a polynomial-time algorithm to check whether there exists at least one satisfying matrix (max flow with a capacity lower/upper bound wherever a matrix entry is specified). This leads straightforwardly to a polynomial-delay enumeration algorithm: walk a tree where each internal node corresponds to a decision between "increase the current matrix entry by one" or "move to the next entry".

Comment: Does it have a name?  Do you know if an efficient algorithm has been implemented?

Comment: @AAK It's a combination of two off-the-shelf parts, so probably not named. No idea about implementations.

Comment: For fixed K, an implementation of the algorithm you describe is relatively straightforward, I think.  For general K, I can envision solutions based on recursion.  I was hoping to learn that someone solves this problem routinely in some context or other.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be framed a problem in linear algebra and/or integer linear programming. There are `k x k` variables and `k + k` equations. The system can be reduced by a standard technique, e.g., Smith Normal Form. The problem with this approach is ensuring that all the variables are non-negative. I suspect that to find all solutions you'll just have to step through the parameter space, stopping when a negative number appears. I doubt there is a more efficient method, but that's just an intuition.

Alternatively you could think of the problem as an Integer Linear Programming problem, with a constant (or otherwise immaterial) objective like `minimize 0x_{ij}` or `minimize d` where `d` is not a variable which appears elsewhere. See http://www.aiexp.info/calculating-all-feasible-solutions-of-ilp.html for an example.

Anyway, back to linear algebra. Since there are `k^2` variables and `2k-1` constraints (one of the constraints is redundant because the sum of all the "across" equations equals the sum of all the "down" equations), there are `k^2-2k+1 = (k-1)^2` free variables. That should make us look for a square submatrix of free variables. Indeed, we can take any square minor (for example the upper left `(k-1)x(k-1)` corner) as free. That will determine the values in positions `(i,k)`, `i<k`, and in positions `(k,j)`, `j<k`. Finally, the bottom corner `(k,k)` is determined either by all the entries above it or to the left of it. (The two methods should agree.)

Using this idea, I see two different ways to proceed. The first way is to fill in the free variables starting with the square `(k-1)x(k-1)` submatrix of all 1's and augmenting them odometer style. At each step, calculate the edge and corner variables, and stop augmenting a certain digit when one of the calculated values hits 0. It is possible to permute the rows and or columns so that the smallest sums are used when it is strategic (either first or last, I'm not sure). I've done this by hand for k=3 and it works. It takes a long time just because there are a lot of answers.

A smarter way to proceed is as follows. Instead of determining the `(k-1)x(k-1)` submatrix, determine the other values on the edges (the `(i,k)` and `(k,j)` positions). The corner is "overdetermined" so we have to be careful of the order in which we do things, but otherwise it's straightforward. Then that tells us what the sum of the remaining elements in each row and column should be, so we have reduced the problem on the `kxk` matrix to the problem on the `(k-1)x(k-1)` matrix. In other words, we can use recursion.

It's instructive to walk through the process with the `k=3` problem where all the rows and columns sum to 4. The various ways of filling in the right and bottom edges are as follows:

```
XX1 XX1 XX1 XX2 XX2
XX1 XX2 XX2 XX1 XX1
112 121 211 121 211
```

In the first case we get the reduced problem

```
XX = 3
XX = 3
==
33
```

To solve that we proceed as above, with the smaller matrix. The possible edges are

```
X1 X2
12 21
```

which lead directly to the solutions

```
21 12
12 21
```

Substituting those into the `3x3` matrix from which they came, we get the following solutions to the original problem:

```
211 121
121 211
112 112
```

Next consider the `3x3` situation

```
XX1
XX2
121
```

That gives rise to the `2x2` problem

```
XX=3
XX=2
==
32
```

The only edge that works in that case is

```
X1
11
```

which gives the only solution

```
21
11
```

Substituting back into the `3x3` situation from which it came, we get another solution to the original problem,

```
211
112
121
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks!  This is very useful.  Following your insight, I implemented a recursive solution to the problem.  Of course, it will only be practical when K is small.  One improvement to the algorithm you describe is achieved by recognizing that the problem is essentially the same if the matrix is not square.  The recursion is then column-by-column.  Specifically, for each admissible value of the first column (say), recursively enumerate all admissible values of the smaller table obtained by deleting the first column.